# Multidimensional array iteration with ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a dataset like that:

```
   [
        {
            prop1: "",
            prop2: "",
            child: [
                prop1: "",
                prop2: "",
                    child: [
                    ...
                    ]
            ]
        },
        {
            prop1: "",
            prop2: "",
            child: [
                prop1: "",
                prop2: "",
                    child: [
                    ...
                    ]
            ]
        }
    ],
[
        {
            prop1: "",
            prop2: "",
            child: [
                prop1: "",
                prop2: "",
                    child: [
                    ...
                    ]
            ]
        },
        {
            prop1: "",
            prop2: "",
            child: [
                prop1: "",
                prop2: "",
                    child: [
                    ...
                    ]
            ]
        }
    ],
```

This can go deeper forever, it is not a two or three-dimensional array. It is an N-dimensional array. I was thinking of how to properly iterate it in the HTML, but using nested ngFor would be a suicide and kinda impossible since, as I said, I don't know how many nested children I will have.

What I want is a tree view of that dataSet.

What could be a good solution to this?

Comment: Lets start with what and why you want to iterate over for your template? What are you trying to show / do? If all you want is to flatten it then do that in the code behind (component) using recursion and then display that flattened model in the template.

Comment: How you want to view the data ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've added now the detail. I'm trying to think a way on how to display a tree view of that array.

Comment: I don't know if 'pure' angular is the right decision for this.
A graph library may be more successful.

Comment: @CitrusPunk Material does this in a very well way. I can't sadly use it because I need a very custom setup

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Which Angular Material Component do you mean? May I look into it.

Comment: @CitrusPunk that's the Material Tree Component: https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview

Comment: Firstly your dataset is incorrect. You have array inside a object? Your structure is quite confusing and misleading. Please add your actual structure or correct it. And also an example of your expected output which you wanted. So that we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive component, let call it displayobject. For each level, the displayobject component list the properties, if the property is a string then it displays it, otherwise it loads a new displayobject component that do the same thing with the given object.

Template :

```
<div *ngFor="let property of propertyList">

    <span *ngIf="isString(myObject[property])"> 
        {{ property }} 
    </span>

    <displayobject *ngIf="isObject(myObject[property])" [myObject]="myObject[property]">
    </displayobject>

</div>
```

Component :

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'displayobject',
    ...
})
export class DisplayObject {

    @Input() myObject;
    public propertyList = [];

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.propertyList = Object.keys(this.myObject);
    }
}
```

And you call it :

```
 <displayobject [myObject]="yourObject"></displayobject>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following @Noelmout solution but getting in a simpler way.

The idea is the set a recursive component.
Since the data set you just shown satisfies a pattern like `{prop1: "", prop2: "", child: [...]}` and so on. Consider a component to render recursively and typed.

*.ts

```
type Item = {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string,
  child: Item[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'item-display',
  templateUrl: './item-display.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-display.component.scss']
})
export class ItemDisplayComponent {
  @Input() item: Item;
}
```

*.html

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="prop1">{{ item.prop1 }}</div>
    <div class="prop2">{{ item.prop2 }}</div>

    <div class="child" *ngFor="let c of item.child">
        <item-display [item]="c"></item-display>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now, you can modify anything on the component that will be applied to all the nested components.
Even more, add a `depth` attribute, if needed

```
...
@Input() depth: number = 0; // or 1, up to you
```

```
<item-display [item]="c" [depth]="depth + 1"></item-display>
```

And finally, since you have a collection of that items, from you root component

```
<div class="item-display" *ngFor="let item of rootItems">
    <item-display [item]="item"></item-display>
</div>
```

No need to set the depth property because has a default value (and better off not to expose that property, it is like a internal field just know by `ItemDisplayComponent`).